# React Component Save and Reset Textarea

Tags: reactjs, textarea

I'm trying to make a textarea component that would be part of a larger form, but I want the ability to save or cancel on the element. Similar to how some of the Jira fields work if you've used that. What I have is likely suboptimal as I feel like I've just been hacking things together to get it to work. (The delay on the outFocus function killed me for a while as the button was being hidden before I could click it but that delay did the trick!). My problem now is that the cancel button doesn't always work after I save an item. When the form loads it comes in with a default value and after saving that default value should be overwritten. It's very strange that it only works 80% of the time.

(Please pick apart the code if you enjoy that - I'm very new to React and would love to learn how to do things better!)

Here is my custom Textarea component that has save / cancel buttons pop up onFocus and they go away after a delay onBlur.

```
import './index.css'
import { useState } from 'react';


function TextareaSaveCancel({ label, name, save, default_value, on_change, ...attributes }) {

  const [saveShow, setSaveShow] = useState('none')
  const [textAreaValue, setTextAreaValue] = useState(default_value)

  const onTextAreaChange = (e) => {
    setTextAreaValue(e.target.value)
    on_change(e)
  }

  const inFocus = () => {
    setSaveShow('block')
  }

  const outFocus = (e) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      setSaveShow('none')
    }, 250);
  }

  const reset = (e) => {
    setTextAreaValue(default_value)
  }

  const saveField = () => {
    default_value = textAreaValue
    save({[name]: textAreaValue})
  }


  return (
    <div className="save-field" style={{position: 'relative'}}>
      <label className="form-label lead">{label}</label>
      <textarea className="form-control" {...attributes} onFocus={inFocus} onBlur={outFocus} onChange={onTextAreaChange} value={textAreaValue} name={name}></textarea>
      <div className="save-options btn-group btn-group-sm" style={{ display: saveShow, position: 'absolute', right: 0 }}>
        <button className="btn btn-outline-secondary" type='button' onClick={saveField}><i className="bi bi-floppy-fill"></i></button>
        <button className="btn btn-outline-secondary" type='button' onClick={reset}><i className="bi bi-x-circle"></i></button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default TextareaSaveCancel;
```

Here is how I'm using the component in a form:

```
import { EOApi } from 'src/apis/eo';
import './index.css'
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';
import TextareaSaveCancel from 'src/components/TextareaSaveCancel';

function EngineeringOrder() {
  let { id } = useParams()

  const [data, setData] = useState(false);
  const [structure, setstructure] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData(id)
  }, [])

  const fetchData = async (id) => {
    try {
      const response = await EOApi.getStructure()
      // console.log(response.data.actions.POST)
      const data_response = await EOApi.getById(id)
      // console.log(data_response.data)
      setstructure(response.data.actions.POST)
      setData(data_response.data)
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  }

  const [formData, setFormData] = useState("")

  const handleChange = (event, editor) => {
    let name = '';
    let value = '';

    if (editor) {
      name = 'description' // Don't know how to get this from the CKEditor, hardcoding it which works when there is only one instance of it
      value = editor.getData()
    } else {
      name = event.target.name;
      value = event.target.value;
    }
    setFormData(values => ({ ...values, [name]: value }))
  }

  // const handleSubmit = () => console.log(formData)
  const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    // e.preventDefault();
    // console.log(formData)
    const resp = await EOApi.patch(id, formData)
    console.log(resp)
    setData(formData)
    setFormData("")
  }

  const handleFieldSave = async (fieldData) => {
    const name = Object.keys(fieldData)[0]
    const resp = await EOApi.patch(id, fieldData)
    setData(resp.data)
    delete formData[name]
  }


  return (
    <>
      {structure && data ?
        <div className="container">
          <h1 className='display-5'>EO-{data.eo_number.toString().padStart(6, '0')}</h1>
          <hr />
          <form >
            <h4><u>Affected Parts</u></h4>
            <div className="row mb-3">
              <div className="col">
                <TextareaSaveCancel label="Problem Items" name='problem_items' save={handleFieldSave} on_change={handleChange} default_value={data['problem_items']} />
                <small className="form-text text-muted">Comma separated</small>
              </div>
              <div className="col">
                <TextareaSaveCancel label="Solution Items" name='solution_items' save={handleFieldSave} on_change={handleChange} default_value={data['solution_items']} />
                <small className="form-text text-muted">Comma separated</small>
              </div>
            </div>

            <button className="btn btn-primary" type="button" onClick={handleSubmit}>Save Data</button>
          </form>
        </div>
        :
        <div className="d-flex justify-content-center">
          <div className="spinner-border m-5" role="status">
          </div>
        </div>
      }
    </>
  );
}

export default EngineeringOrder;
```